# Way to work on live website without displaying it?

Tags: web, content-management-system

This is my first website. I am developing website using Drupal 7 CMS. As a first website, the development I am doing on my computers local server which is i guess normal practice. Is there a way where I can do the same thing on the hosted serves with actual domain name, But when somebody other person visit to my domain it will just show the page of 'Website Under Construction', While on the back side I can do the actual work on the actual environment and when my website done just I can remove that 'Under Construction' page and website gets live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use the maintenance mode so the users will see a courtesy page message while you can work, as admin, on your site.
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/how-to-put-drupal-7-in-maintenance-mode/
if you want you can also theme your maintenance mode adding text, images, mail addresses, countdown etc.

Comment: If you use drush (wich highly recommand to accelerate tasks greatly), you can get in maintenance mode with : drush vset maintenance_mode 1

Comment: @ll No,Sorry for late reply, however I had already accepted this as answer as it solved my issue. Thank you very much.